# How to calculate this iterated integral:$\int_0^1dy\int_0^y dx\int_0^x \frac{e^z}{1-z}dz$?

Tags: calculus, iterated-integrals

Is there any trivial way to calculate this iterated integral,$\int_0^1dy\int_0^ydx\int_0^x\frac{e^z}{1-z}dz$? I've already solved this by taking series expansion of $e^x$ into the integral,but I wonder if there is any other easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your joint support is

$$0<z<x<y<1$$

thus first integrate in $dy$ obtaining

$$\frac{e^z}{1-z}\int_x^1 dy=\frac{e^z}{1-z}(1-x)$$

now your support is

$$0<z<x<1$$

and you can integrate

$$\int_0^1\frac{e^z}{1-z}\left[\int_z^1(1-x)dx\right]dz=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(1-z)e^z dz=\frac{e-2}{2}$$